# How do I code ListBox RowSource property using worksheet and table name in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I know I can fill in the information in the Properties window, but I would like to learn how to code the property.

After browsing the internet, this is the code I tried (Chart_of_Accts is a table in the "Chart of Accounts" worksheet):

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    ListBox1.RowSource = _
      Worksheets("Chart of Accounts").Range("Chart_of_Accts").Address(0, 0, , 1)
End Sub
```

I'm fairly new to VBA. I've tried different iterations of the same line of code (e.g., using cell names instead of the name of the table), without success. If there is more than one way of coding for this, I would appreciate to know other options as well.

EDIT:

Here's a screenshot after inserting new code suggested in answer (listbox still comes up empty):

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wqbL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `UserForm_Initialize` to load items for ListBox
- `Range("Chart_of_Accts")` is the data body range (w/o header row) in the table (ListObject). It is same as `ListObjects("Chart_of_Accts").DataBodyRange`. I prefer to use the latter one.
- Use `ColumnCount` and `ColumnHeads` property in `UserForm_Initialize` event

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ColumnCount property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/columncount-property?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(fm20.chm2000940)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [ColumnHeads property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/columnheads-property?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Initialize event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/initialize-event?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tabRange As Range
    Set tabRange = Worksheets("Chart of Accounts").ListObjects("Chart_of_Accts").DataBodyRange
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = tabRange.Columns.Count
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = tabRange.Address(, , , True)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to either reread a few chapters in my textbook, or find a new one! When I use the Properties window of the ListBox object to fill in RowSource and then hit "Run" from the code window, the ListBox pops up with the list of items from my table. However inserting your code in the UserForm and hitting Run just gives me an empty ListBox. What am I missing? Do I need to add the code to a module before I can test it?

Comment: * What I meant to say in my last sentence was : add an instance of the listbox inside a module

Comment: I've upload a gif. I guess the code wasn't stored in UserForm's module. It's helpful if you could share a screenshot.

Comment: Sure thing, I added a screenshot in my original post.

Comment: Pls add `MsgBox tabRange.Address(, , , True)` before `End Sub` to check the value.

Comment: I did, but no message box comes up when I run the code...

Comment: It's weired. Please copy `Chart of Accounts` to creat a new workbook, insert an UserForm with a ListBox, then test the code.

Comment: Right, that did it. I went back into my other workbook, deleted the userform and created a new one (which I had already tried doing once), and now it works in that workbook also. I'm completely at a loss. I did notice that in my window, the left drop down in the coding window said "General", as opposed to "Userform"... even though I was in the userform window. Also notice that now that I deleted and created a new userform, the sub UserForm1_Click() is gone. I hadn't manually written it, so it was populated automatically at some point... Does that give any indication as to what was going on?

Comment: If the cursor (edit point) is on the line `Option Explicit`, it shows `General`. That's normal. `Userform` show up if you move the cursor into `UserForm_Initialize()`.  Whether the UserForm module has `UserForm1_Click()` depends on how you open the code window. If you right-click on the UserForm and select `View Code`, it will automatically create that procedure.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you for all your help! I was going a little nuts with this